# Dependency property not passing the default value on initial binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dependency-properties

I have a custom button and I have setup a dependency property on the Foreground, the events are raising fine apart from the first attempt where a null is passed instead of the expected blue solid color brush.

The code changes the color fine on subsequent calls so it is just the initial setting I have a problem with. Any help would be appreciated please.

Here is my code:

```
    Public Shared Shadows ReadOnly ForegroundProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Foreground",
   GetType(Brush), GetType(TouchButton), New PropertyMetadata(New SolidColorBrush With {.Color = Colors.Blue},
   New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnForegroundChanged)))
```

Comment: Control already has a Foreground property. If your TouchButton doesn't inherit from control that would be a bit strange naming but I suppose still possible. If it does then you have two foreground properties which will mean strange behaviour.  Either way, I strongly recommend a unique name for any dependency property you add.

Comment: I am Shadowing the dependency property and using Overload on the foreground property which allows me to use Foreground as a Dependency. As I say it works in every other aspect but just does not set the default value.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue, it was in my binding that I was adding in code at run-time as the controls are added dynamically.